# What are the differences between Barcelona Pass vs Barcelona Card vs Barcelona City Pass?

Tags: tickets, spain, barcelona

**Background:** Traveling in December 2017-January 2018 and planning on visiting the usual spots (Park Güell, Camp Nou, Montjuïc, a lot of Gaudi's work, etc).

It seems like two are private, one is government-run, which only makes it more confusing:

1. http://bcnshop.barcelonaturisme.com/shopv3/en/product/buy/1/barcelona-card.html?o=h
2. http://bcnmuseumeng.rgi.ticketbar.eu/en/ticketbar-barcelona/#TopProducts
3. https://www.barcelonapass.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found this out from [this forum](https://community.ricksteves.com/travel-forum/spain/about-city-passes-when-visiting-barcelona).

- Barcelona only has 2 official ticket passes (Barcelona city hall and Transports Metropolitans de Barcelona (TMB)
- Rest are private sellers and variations
- NO, there is no single pass for the top10 sites, neither for "the Gaudí sites"
- NO, there is no single pass that will allow you to "skip the lines".

> Officially, **the only city passes for the city of Barcelona are the ones sold by [Turisme de Barcelona --the Barcelona Tourism Consortium](http://bcnshop.barcelonaturisme.com)-- a public company dependant of the Barcelona City Hall.** and in their jargon they call these sort of passes "multitickets". These are the ones available at present.
>
> There's yet **another type of passes, sold by Transports Metropolitans de Barcelona (TMB) --the Barcelona Metropolitan Transport Authority-- aimed to those visitors interested in transportation only. [The available passes are the called HolaBCN](https://www.tmb.cat/en/barcelona/fares-metro-bus/barcelona-travel-card-hola-bcn) -free transportation for a period of 2 days up to 5 days** - and the Integrated Travel Cards that can also be interesting to visitors, being the T-10 travelcard the most popular and convenient: a multiperson card with 10 journeys for roughly 10€ (not in vain is the most used by Barcelonians themselves).
>
> Lastly, the private company running one of the two hop-on-hop-off bus lines, Barcelona City Tour, has recently launched a card, called iventure, which offers discounts to some attractions, much like the Barcelona Card sold by Turisme de Barcelona above.

Answer (score 1):

Barcelona Card is run by local tourist office – it's the most popular tourist card in the city and skip the line option should be included in the card.

Barcelona Pass and Barcelona City pass are commercial cards.

For comparison see site: http://barcelonacards.com/